# class based styles in material-ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material-ui and after my first test (material v0.18.7 and react v15.6.1), I found out that it uses inline styles for each component.
I tested with placing the same component for 10 times and there was no class based styling (using CSS) it was all just repeating inline styles.
As in a real web page, there might be so many components having same styles, is there any better way to stop doing this redundant styling and add some css or something like that , that can reduce the size of data being passed to the user at each page loading?

I mean any thing that can help me reduce the amount of inline styles where they can be handled in another way

this is my sample code

```
<div>
    <Paper style={style} zDepth={1} ><FlatButton label="exit" /></Paper>
    <Paper style={style} zDepth={1} ><FlatButton label="exit" /></Paper>
    <Paper style={style} zDepth={1} ><FlatButton label="exit" /></Paper>
</div>
```

I render this simple component with react and the output html file has the following `div` three times:

```
<div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; z-index: 1; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; min-width: 88px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; border-radius: 2px; user-select: none; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <span style="position: relative; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; vertical-align: middle; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px;">exit</span>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

the exact `div` is added to my code three times, with all inline styles.

I'm asking for a way to reduce the amount of these inline styles and change them with some css code.

thanks

Comment: hey @rkarami, the component property to use is `className`. Then you can use a stylesheet doc / block to define the styles.

Comment: @yomexzo i know how to add classes in react, i had a big problem with those inline styles in react and specially in this library

Comment: i see what you mean @rkarami. i share the same sentiments. The styles are added by the materialui library. May be they used that considering rendering on all devices (mobile especially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I understand what you are trying to do. If your intention is to reduce the use of inline style called by material ui for material-ui related components you're going to have to edit the material ui css plugin files directly... But I don't recommend doing that. 
You can always override the css styling by using `!important` but that won't remove the other arguments passed by material-ui, it will simply override the existing ones. 
In your case I see only two options: either you create a new type of `<FlatButton/>` yourself using what material ui has already done for you and adapt it just for your page (but it might take up a lot of time), or you just roll with what material ui has to offer and override the elements that bother you.
To be perfectly honest however, I'm not sure the inline styling you see in your browser have a considerable slowing potential on the loading time of your page. 
Hope I answered your question!
D.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an open discussion on this here, and from what i've read, they're not decided on a way to implement external CSS: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1132

You could also have a look into a theme provider for MUI.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-theme-provider

Comment: i read that discussion before asking question, the problem is i'm not looking for a way to implement my own style over the default style, i am trying to find a way to remove these redundant styles from my html because what i see is large amount of redundant style being passed to client every time my page loads.

Answer (score -1):

Why not pass all the elements you wish to give the same inline style into the same class? And then in css you can simply define all your parameters relevant to the styling of those components through this class. For example:

HTML

```
<div class = "thing"></div>
```

CSS

```
.thing {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm not passing the styles, material-ui is passing them and i thin i can't change that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is here. Perhaps providing some code could allow me to help you better.